# "Playground" usage

Tags: word-usage

"Playground" meaning according to dictionary.cambridge.org.

1. An area designed for children to play in outside, especially at a school or in a park.
2. A place where a particular group of people enjoy themselves

I'd like to have a sentence based on conditions:

1. There's a river.
2. Many children often down the river to play or to fish.

My question:

Could I use the word of "playground" in this case?

"For many children, the river is to be a fun playground".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that use rather odd, but I would say

> Many children make the river a playground.

or

> Many children make a playground of the river.

The use of "make" implies that the river isn't really a playground ("an area **designed** for children to play in") but that they regard it that way.

One other point: "is to be" means "somebody is planning that": I don't think it's what you mean here.

Answer (score 1):

When the word **playground** is used figuratively to refer to *any* place where people go to have fun, it could be used of almost anything:

> The town dump was their playground.
>
> The Riviera was their playground.
>
> The riverbank was the village playground.
>
> Virtual reality was their favorite playground.